# Complex use of QThread -

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I have wrote an app in QT/C++. This app have multiple classes to manage window, treewidget.. and a custom class.

The goal of the app is to be android file transfer -like in QT/c++ on MacOSx.

Currently the entire app is working in one thread which include the UI management and the android device management. The android device access is managed by a class named DeviceManager. This class will mostly open the device, read it, add/delete files....

What I want to do is to create a thread which will handle all method defined in the DeviceManager. I want the UI on one thread and the devicemngr in a separate thread.

Here is my current code :

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PULS_mtp_error_t error = ERROR_GENERAL;
    QThread PulsDeviceThread;

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    DeviceMngr *MyMtp = new DeviceMngr;
    error = MyMtp->OpenDevice();
    ...
    MainUI MyWindow(*MyMtp);
    MyWindow.show();
    return app.exec();

}
```

the MainUI class is defined as below

```
MainUI::MainUI(DeviceMngr& device) :
    m_device(device)
{

    m_closing = false;

    setWindowTitle(QString::fromUtf8("PULS"));
    resize(800,600);
    setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(true);
    /* Creation of the Top bar section */
    createBackForwardButton();
    createLogoSection();
    createAddFolder();

    QWidget *TopBarWidget = new QWidget();
    TopBarWidget->setFixedHeight(61);
    QHBoxLayout *TopBarLayout = new QHBoxLayout(TopBarWidget);
    TopBarLayout->addWidget(BackForwardSection);
    TopBarLayout->addWidget(LogoSection);
    TopBarLayout->addWidget(AddFolderSection);

    /* Creation of Tree View Section */
    createTreeView();

    /* Creation of the bottom bar section */
    createInfoSection();

    /*about*/
    aboutAction = new QAction(tr("&About"),this);
    connect(aboutAction, SIGNAL(triggered()),this ,SLOT(aboutPuls()));

    QMenu *helpMenu = new QMenu("Help", this);
    helpMenu->addAction(aboutAction);
    menuBar()->addMenu(helpMenu);

    /*Overall Layout*/
    QWidget *MainWindowWidget = new QWidget();
    QVBoxLayout *MainWindowLayout = new QVBoxLayout(MainWindowWidget);

    MainWindowLayout->setSpacing(0);
    MainWindowLayout->addWidget(TopBarWidget);
    MainWindowLayout->addWidget(TreeViewSection);
    MainWindowLayout->addWidget(CreateInfoSection);

    setCentralWidget(MainWindowWidget);

    PulsUnplugged = false;
#if 1
    activeTimer = new QTimer(this);
    activeTimer->setSingleShot(false);
    activeTimer->setInterval(200);
    connect(activeTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(PulsDetection()));
    activeTimer->start();
#endif
    show();
}
```

Some of the method such as createTreeView will use the m_device to access also to the device.

```
void MainUI::createTreeView()
{

    TreeViewSection = new QWidget();

    QVBoxLayout *TreeViewLayout = new QVBoxLayout(TreeViewSection);

    MyTreeWidget = new MyNewTreeWidget(m_device, *this);

    TreeViewLayout->addWidget(MyTreeWidget);
}
```

MyNewTreeWidget will also need to access to the DeviceMngr class.

Most of class used for the UI management can access to the DeviceMngr class. I don't know how to use the QThread to make sure that all UI classes can access to the DeviceMngr class.

I was thinking to create a Qthread in the main.cpp but I do not see how to add slots/signals in the main.cpp and DeviceMngr will have signals/slots to discuss with all other thread. the main will need for example to open the device and receive the result.

Do I need to create all signal/slot connection in the main or I can just add what I need in the different classes and create the connections when needed.

Any idea ? I have tried a first implementation but it not really working fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating the worker thread and moving your `DeviceMngr` to it. Its slots (and whole event loop) will run in the context of the thread and you must use Qt's signal/slot mechanism that will ensure thread safe access to `DeviceMngr` from other QObjects.

```
int main(...) {
    // ...
    QThread MtpThread;
    DeviceMngr MyMtp;
    MyMtp.moveToThread(&MtpThread);

    // connect signals/slots of DeviceMngr
    // ...

    // launch the thread
    MtpThread.start();

    // should you need to call slots of DeviceMngr from main use metacalls
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&MyMtp, "nameOfSlot");

    // run application

    // in the end join
    MtpThread.quit(); // stop event queue
    MtpThread.wait(); // join the thread
}
```

I hope you get the idea. Key is `moveToThread()` and metacalls.

Comment: but when the class MainUI or MyTreeWidget need to access, where do I need to put all the connect ?? Can I declare everything in main ? such as connect(this, SIGNAL(ckjskjgkls), MyTreeWidget, SLOT(MyTreeWidget::nameOfApi)) or something like this ?

Comment: For example in MyTreeWidget I have an action to create a folder which call the DeviceMngr method create folder. I'm using in my code m_device as ref to access to the instantiate class.

Comment: From the context of `MyTreeWidget` you may use abovementioned metacalls or just declare a signal and emit it instead of the call. The actual connection is a runtime thing. I would suggest calling it from some place where you have access to both connected objects. `main` is good option for this. Or you could create some "builder" class that'll do it all.